# Inside a loop, how to indicate "all rows" when taking the mean of multiple columns (Visual Basic)

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, statistics

I have a loop wherein I take the mean of several columns of numbers with the same number of rows each.

The point of the loop is to capture these means in a new vector.

So for each loop I need to indicate "all rows".  In matlab this would be easy, just use ":"  But I can't figure out what the analogy is in VB.  Please help!  Thanks.

(Please advise me as to what I put in the code below where I have **ALLROWS**).

My attempt so far:

```
   For i = 1 To CA
        mrCA11(i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(revCA11(**ALLROWS**,i))
   Next i
```

In matlab this would be:

```
   For i = 1:CA
        mrCA11(i) = mean(revCA11(:,i));
   Next i
```

EDIT: I've also tried this trick to no avail:

```
    For j = 1 To CA
        For i = 1 To s11
             temp11(i) = revCA11(i, j)
        Next i
        mrCA11(j) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(temp11)
    Next j
```

I get the error message: "Unable to get the Average property of the Worksheet Function class"

Comment: Is this specifically in the context of Excel? If so, you might want to use the [tag:excel] tag.

Comment: Yes.  Just added the tag.  Thanks.

Comment: @ben: What is `revCA11`?

Comment: Visual Basic or VBA? If this is VB, then please remove the VBA tag - it will confuse people.

Comment: `Application.WorksheetFunction` leads me to believe this is Excel VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everybody (Tim and shahkalpesh at least) pointed out, we need to understand what is `revCall` or more specifically, we need to understand how you want to give them `ALL ROWS` in argument.

### Finding the last row (or column or cell)

A common Excel issue is to find the last used row / column / cell.
This will give you the end of your vector.

Excel give you several methods to deal with this:

#### xlTypeLastCell

Last cell used in the entire sheet (regardless if it's used in column A or not)

```
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
```

#### End(xlUp)

Last cell used (including blanks in-between) in Column A is as simple as this:

```
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

#### End(xlToLeft)

Last cell used (including blanks in-between) in Row 1 is as simple as this:

```
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Row
```

#### UsedRange

Last cell used in the WorkSheet (according to Excel interpretation):

```
Set rangeLastCell = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
```

### Using an array as argument

The methods above told you how to find the last row (if this is what you need). You can then easily create your vector and use it in your procedure `revCA11`.

You can either give an **array as argument** as Tim pointed out in his answer with this kind of statement:

```
myArray = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", Cells(lastRow, lastColumn).Value
```

Or you can use the integer (or long) to build your vector inside your procedure as simple as declaring a range:

```
Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might clarify exactly how `revCA11` is declared/created, but maybe something along these lines might work for you:

```
Sub Tester()

Dim arr, x
arr = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:D5").Value '2-D array

'average each column
Debug.Print "Columns:"
For x = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
    Debug.Print x, Application.Average(Application.Index(arr, 0, x))
Next x

'average each row
Debug.Print "Rows:"
For x = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
    Debug.Print x, Application.Average(Application.Index(arr, x, 0))
Next x

End Sub
```